# How to make jQuery dialog working with hyperlink text instead of button?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, dialog, popup, jquery-ui-dialog

I made it work but the problem is that it works only once. Once the popup appears , the link doesn't work and the popup doesnt show up again. I have to refresh to see that is happening. I got this http://jsfiddle.net/pjVcR/2/ and it works inside the jsfiddle , but in my site it doesn't work. My site link is here : [MY SITE](http://aasiskos.webpages.auth.gr/NAUTILUS/prosopiko.html)

Here is the code:

```
  <div class="content">
  <h4><a href="#" >AAAA</a></h4><img src="AAAA.jpg" />
    <div class="dialog" title="AAAA" >text AAAA
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
  <h4><a href="#" >BBBB</a><br></h4><br><img src="BBBB.jpg" />
    <div class="dialog" title="BBBB" >text
    </div>
  </div>
```

and the script given in the html as well :

```
<script>
$("a").click(function(event) {
  $(this).parent().parent().children(".dialog").dialog({
    close: function( event, ui ) {
      $('.dialog').dialog('destroy');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: First of all, make sure that you do not have multiple controls with the same ID. In your example you have two links wit I `OpenDialog`. Also, your site works fine for me... Could you explain if you are getting errors? What happens? What is supposed to happen? What browsers have you tested this in?

Comment: @NikitaSilverstruk I tested it in chrome. id="OpenDialog" is useless.

Comment: @NikitaSilverstruk when you click on <a> to open the dialog box, and then you close it, can you open it again? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome and FF, but I am getting an error in the console.

Comment: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many elements with the `dialog` class, so when you call

```
$('.dialog').dialog('destroy');
```

you are destroying dialogs that do not yet exist,  thus the exception:

> cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to
>   call method 'destroy'

Use the local instance of `$(this)` inside the `close` handler (which is that specific `.dialog` element) so that jQuery knows which one to destroy.

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
  $(this).parent().parent().children(".dialog").dialog({
    close: function( event, ui ) {
      $(this).dialog('destroy');
    }
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pjVcR/3/

Notice if you change the code to use `.dialog` instead of `$(this)` you will still get the same error you are getting in your page, and that's why you don't get the error in the jsFiddle, because you only have one div with class `.dialog` in there.

Comment: It worked. In your jsfiddle you put OpenDialog and OpenDialog2. But id="OpenDialog" is useless. So it works without it or with it without having to change names to OpenDialog2, OpenDialog3 etc.

Comment: @ApoloRadomer, ah yeah I was just testing around, but yeah that does not matter.

Comment: People now often run ajax to load data like that into the modal boxes.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is that when you call

`$('.dialog').dialog('destroy');`

You are destroying the object/it does no longer exist, You would need to recreate it instead of just calling it..

Try creating a class that you can put on your href tag that will give you what you are looking for

Try doing this:

`<a href="PageName.php" class="iframe_popup" title="Title You want The Dialog Box to show">Your Text Link here</a>`

```
$(function() {

$('.iframe_popup').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();         
    var $this = $(this);
    var horizontalPadding = 30;
    var verticalPadding = 30;

    var iframe_popup = $('<iframe id="externalSite" class="externalSite" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" src="' + this.href + '" />');
    iframe_popup.dialog(
    {
        title: ($this.attr('title')) ? $this.attr('title') : '',
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 600,
        height: 450,
        modal: true,
        autoResize: true,
        overlay: {
            opacity: 0.5,
            background: "black"
        }
    }).width(600 - horizontalPadding).height(450 - verticalPadding);
});

}); // Close Function
```

Comment: It works very well , but there is another problem. Whenever i click on the hyperlink text , I want a new text to appear in my pop out box. In your code, the box just shows the same text as the TEXT of the hyperlink. Here it is:
<a href="#" class="iframe_popup" title="EPITELOUS">TEXT</a>

Answer (score 0):

`$('.dialog').dialog('destroy');` trys to destroy all you dialogs, not only the visible. thats why you get a error.

try `$('.dialog:visible').dialog('destroy');` to destroy all visible dialogs. Or you can prefix the id for the dialogs and then select and destroy them.

Comment: What error did you get? Worked fine on your site when i tested it.